# Stop registration mail while sending invitation mail in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, devise, devise-invitable

In my application confirmation mail is sent after the entry goes in User's table or new user signs up. But in my application I am also using devise invitable. In that when I do User.invite then the invitation is sent but since the entry also goes in users table the confirmation mail is also sent. But can I stop the confirmation mails being sent while sending the invitation to users. I had added `skip_confirmation: true`while adding the invitation but still the confirmation mails are sent. Can someone suggest some solution for this?

Comment: please post some code

Comment: Had used user = User.invite!(email: "#{email}", name: "#{email}".split('@').first.lstrip, skip_confirmation: true) for sending invitation....

Comment: I think I should customize devise confirmation mails. But not getting how to customize that. Can someone provide some proper link for that?

Comment: Did you see this sentence? You can add :skip_invitation to attributes hash if skip_invitation is added to attr_accessible.

Comment: Yes, have added skip_confirmation to attr_accessible

Answer (score 0):

I did this (and a few other modifications) by altering the devise_invitable controller action for `create`. The [README](https://github.com/scambra/devise_invitable) has a section called "Configuring Controllers" to get you started down this road.

You want to follow the instructions in that section to create a new controller that inherits from Devise::InvitationsController. In the newly-created controller include a `create` method that uses the `skip_confirmation!` method and then `super` (refer) to the parent controller to finish the action.

This is untested code, but you'd have something like:

```
class Users::InvitationsController < Devise::InvitationsController
  def create
      resource.skip_confirmation!    
      super
  end
end
```

When I was figuring out how to modify the default Devise_Invitable behavior, I found looking at the source controller really helpful - [here it is](https://github.com/scambra/devise_invitable/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/invitations_controller.rb).